# How to make a query from a nested collection in firestore using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a nested collection in firestore that I want to make a query from it.

As you can see the first collection called 'businessUsers' and the nested one called 'campaigns',
If I make a query for a field in the 'businessUsers' it's working OK:

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("businessUsers").where('xxx', 
    isEqualTo:filterBusinessResult ).snapshots().map(_businessListFromSnapshot);
```

but how can I make a query to 'campaigns' collection field?
I tried

```
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("businessUsers").doc().collection("campaigns").where('campaignCategory', isEqualTo:filterBusinessResult ).snapshots()
    .map(_businessListFromSnapshot);
```

but it wont work.
Its important to note, that I need **all** the data with 'campaignCategory' == filterBusinessResult

any idea?

Comment: You might also take into consideration reading this article, [How to query collections in Firestore under a certain path?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you want to query a specific user's campaigns, or the campaigns of all users together.

If you want to query the campaigns of a specific user, you need to query under their document:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("businessUsers").doc("your user ID").
  .collection("campaigns")
  .where('campaignCategory', isEqualTo:filterBusinessResult)
```

So you have to know the ID of the `businessUsers` document here.

---

If you want to query across all `campaigns` subcollections are once, that is known as a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) and would look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collectionGroup("campaigns")
  .where('campaignCategory', isEqualTo:filterBusinessResult)
```

The results are going to documents from the `campaigns` collection only, but you can look up the parent document reference for each `DocumentSnapshot` with `docSnapshot.reference.parent.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

When querying something, `.doc()` requires the id of the document you're trying to get. So it's failing because it doesn't know which document in the `businessUsers` collection you're trying to fetch a subcollection on. You probably want to use a `.collectionGroup()` query here. They let you query all subcollections at once ([see documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)). With FlutterFire specifically, it's going to be something like:

```dart
var snapshots = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("campaigns")
                 .where("campaignCategory", isEqualTo: filterBusinessResult)
                 .snapshots();
```